# No setAttribute or getAttribute in editing HTML in the Console Panel

Tags: javascript, console, panel, setattribute

I would like to try to set Attribute in the Console Panel in Chrome.

But without using with the mouse. Example like this:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/edit-html-in-the-console-panel

I wish only to write the JS-CODE with command, for example:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".serial-number").setAttribute("Value","dummy");
```

In the Console Panel Chrome this function setAttribute is not able. Please is there some alternativ way to write CODE with setting Attribute?

Comment: Why would you be setting an attribute on a collection of elements? I don't know what use a collection has for attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a static `nodelist`, So need to iterate this collection which will give access to the element.Then `setAttribute` can be use to set an attribute

```js
var getAllLI = document.querySelectorAll('.demoClass');
getAllLI.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.setAttribute('value', index)
})
```

```html
<input class="demoClass">
<input class="demoClass">
<input class="demoClass">
<input class="demoClass">
```

Comment: thx, very much, i got answers to my problem